# "There is a difference between..." vs "there is the difference between..." is there a difference?

Tags: articles

"There is **a** difference between A and B" OR "There is **the** difference between A and B"?

I am struggling to decide which article to use in such sentences.

Should it be **the** or **a** before **difference**? Google results favour "there is **the** difference" but it does sound a little unnatural to me unless you really mean some specific "difference", hence any day I would use **a** instead of **the**. Can somebody add some more context to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is ***a*** difference...

This just states a fact.

> There is ***the*** difference...

This statement should follow an explanation of the actual difference, and this is now a closing statement.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your last sentence? Why does it have to follow an explanation? Did you mean the other way around -- explanation should follow the "there is the difference between A and B" statement?

Comment: If you detail the actual differences, you can close with *There is the difference...* - because you've just explained it.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence you used, you would almost always write or say, "There is **a** difference between A and B."

Rarely, you might be trying emphasize the larger concept of there being a difference vs. pointing to there specifically being **a difference**. For example: "Is there any reason? Well, there is the difference between A and B. That's a reason." In that case you are using "the difference" as an object, not pointing to **a** particular difference.

It comes down to what you are trying to say--referring to a particular difference, or referring to the fact that the difference exists.

Someone smarter than me will need to chime in with the conjugation/parts of speech rules that make this true.

I think the "a" vs "the" problem is easier for native English speakers they have studied a foreign language (which I have only done poorly) and grappled with when to use "un livre" (a book) or "le livre" (the book).

Shorthand: Think of "a" as one particular, and "the" as the concept.